# Typescript Import module that exports other modules

Tags: typescript

I have two modules:

ModuleA
and
ModuleB

And I have two Classes:
ClassA 
and 
ClassB

I have my classes defined like such:

```
export class ClassA
{
}

export class ClassB
{
}
```

I have my modules defined like such:

```
export * from './ClassA';
export module ModuleA{};

export * from './ClassB';
export module ModuleB{};
```

I also have a containing Module, called ParentModule:

```
export * from './ModuleB';
export * from './ModuleA';

export module ParentModule{}
```

Now, in one of my typescript files, called Test.ts, I have:

```
import { ClassA } from './ParentModule';

class Test extends ClassA
{

}
```

For some reason, its able to find the reference in my IDE, but at runtime, it throws a not defined error.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I believe I will have to first import all the Types from the child modules, then export * =\

Comment: No dice.  I imported All the types into the module, then exported *, but it still didn't work.  Maybe it has to do with the export * syntax not working in TS2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like it has to do with recursively imported modules.

If A is part of the ParentModule, and imports something from that ParentModule besides itself, it will not work correctly.